# swiftui ternary operator in image body doesn`t play animation and transition

Tags: swiftui, conditional-operator

I tried to use a ternary iterator to simplify the dynamic photo processing code , but it seems that this method does not succeed in SwiftUI. Can you explain why?

The following code performs the animation and transition as intended.

```
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @State private var onOff = true
    var image: String
    var nextPhoto: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation(.spring(dampingFraction: 2.825) ) {
                    self.onOff.toggle()
                }
            }) {
                Text("Button")
            }
            
            if onOff {
                Image(image)
                    .transition(.scale)
                    .animation (.default)
            } else {
                Image(nextPhoto)
                    .transition(.scale)
                    .animation (.default)
            }
            
        }
    }
}

struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwiftUIView(image: "photo", nextPhoto: "photo_next")
    }
}
```

[Result of this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huyIQ.jpg)

However, when i use ternary operator, animation stops working. How can I simplify this code with ternary? Any ideas?

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @State private var onOff = true
    var image: String
    var nextPhoto: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation(.spring(dampingFraction: 2.825) ) {
                    self.onOff.toggle()
                }
            }) {
                Text("Button")
            }
            
            Image(onOff ? image : nextPhoto)
                                   .transition(.scale)
                                   .animation (.default)
            
        }
    }
}
```

[Result of this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcqpN.jpg)

I also tried the following option, which also failed.

```
var image = onOff ? self.image : nextPhoto
Image(image)
      .transition(.scale)
      .animation (.default)
```

I can't post animation video, because i has low level reputation, so i`ll post gif of problem like this:
[Result of first code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huyIQ.jpg)
[Result of second code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcqpN.jpg)

Comment: Can you create a [mre]?

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: also - in the example you've provided which works, you have specified "nextPhoto" whereas in the ternary versions, you have specified "nextPhoto.name"

Comment: I think it will be helpful to provide the error itself to understand what is going on as it seems like a valid code from here.

Comment: @rlong405 I updated post and made it more clear.

Comment: Ah it’s an animation issue. I thought you had a functional issue with the ternary. I’ll see if I can have a look tonight but not something I’m hugely familiar with so I suspect I may not be able to help a lot.

Comment: @rlong405 I will be very grateful for your help. I assume that the problem is related to the bug in XCode, and not the code, but how to avoid this situation-I do not know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, though I am not sure about it ,

```
var image = onOff ? self.image : nextPhoto
Image(image)
  .transition(.scale)
  .animation (.default)
```

Comment: It would be great if it was such a simple mistake. However, this is just a typo in the post, I updated it and made it more clear.

Comment: I have got it. In the first way, there are two image view. So when you toggle the onOff, as there two image view, so the animation happens.

But, when you use ternary operator, you just replace the previous image with the new image, thus updating the same image view. So, there's no animation happens as there only one image view.

Comment: How can there be 2 views in the 1st case, if the program enters only one condition?
That is, it is impossible to make an animation using the ternary operator?

Comment: Because, In first way, you did not replace the previous one, just hide and add transition, so it take time to be hidden.

In second, you just replace the imageview with new image. So there is no otherview for transition.